# Hadoop secondary sorting

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapper

I trying to implemented secondary sort, 
And see that url as eg.:https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-algorithms/9781491906170/ch01.html

But my problem it's different, I have a list of product, the year and month and the price like that:

```
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00951
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00952
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00458
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00459
201505011000#######NOTEBOOK11470
201605011000#######NOTEBOOK21471
201705011000#######NOTEBOOK21472
201705011000###GAVETA DE HD01472
201703011000###GAVETA DE HD01473
201705011000###GAVETA DE HD01474
```

Where for eg.: 201505 represent the year and the month, after the # sign I had the product name, and in the and the price 01470 represent 14,70.

What I need to do is get the lower price for each product and show the Year and month of that Price. But I don't know to do that, what I can show are the Lower price and the product.

Here is my program:

**MAPPER**

```
public class GroupMR {
 public static class GroupMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Product, IntWritable> {

    Product prdt = new Product();
    Text cntText = new Text();
    Text YearMonthText = new Text();
    IntWritable price = new IntWritable();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        String produto = line.substring(13, 27);//Nome do produto
        produto = produto.substring(produto.lastIndexOf("#")+1);
        String ano = line.substring(0, 6);
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(27, 32));
        cntText.set(new Text(produto));
        YearMonthText.set(ano);
        price.set(valor);
        Product prdt = new Product(cntText, YearMonthText);
        context.write(prdt, price);
    }
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
public static class GroupReducer extends Reducer<Product, IntWritable, Product, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Product key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        while (values.hasNext()) {
            minValue = Math.min(minValue,values.next().get());
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(minValue));
    }
}
```

**COMPARABLE**

```
private static class Product implements WritableComparable<Product> {

    Text Product;
    Text YearMonth;

    public Product(Text Product, Text YearMonth) {
        this.Product = Product;
        this.YearMonth = YearMonth;
    }
    public Product() {
        this.Product = new Text();
        this.YearMonth = new Text();
    }

     public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
         this.Product.write(out);
         this.YearMonth.write(out);
     }

     public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
         this.Product.readFields(in);
         this.YearMonth.readFields(in);
     }

     public int compareTo(Product pric) {
        if (pric == null)
            return 0;
        int intcnt = Product.compareTo(pric.Product);
            return intcnt; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Product.toString() + " DATA: " + YearMonth.toString();
    }
}
```

**DRIVER**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("/Local/data/output"));
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "GroupMR");
    job.setJarByClass(GroupMR.class);
    job.setMapperClass(GroupMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(GroupReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Product.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

**RESULT**

```
201605011000######PEN DRIVE00950
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00951
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00952
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00458
201505011000######PEN DRIVE00459
201505011000#######NOTEBOOK11470
201605011000#######NOTEBOOK21471
201705011000#######NOTEBOOK21472
201705011000###GAVETA DE HD01472
201703011000###GAVETA DE HD01473
201705011000###GAVETA DE HD01474
```

I think the problem is in the Reduce and in the CompareTo But I have no idea how to make. Someone could help me with it?

Comment: It doesnt really sound like you need a secondary sort for this problem, and if you do want to do one you're missing some code. If you make the key the product, and the value the date and amount, you can just keep the lowest price in the reduce and output that and its date.

Comment: Hi thanks for respond, could you help how i do it without secondary sort? I am very noob em java.Yes I want to product as a key , but int the output show the Year_moth(that occorred the lowest price) and price
Thanks!